# UITableViewCell Display multiple fonts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to display two words in the uitableviewcell in different fonts similar to the iPhone Address Book.
Ex: John **Buchanan**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you should use two UILables, or you can use [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/Ali-Cocoa-Classes/tree/master/OHAttributedLabel) to draw NSAttributedString..

EDIT:

You can change the UILabel size dynamically using,

```
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [titleLabel.text sizeWithFont:titleLabel.font]; 
titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(xBase, yBase, expectedLabelSize.width, expectedLabelSize.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Jack
Use **cell.textLabel.text** and **cell.textLabel.DetailText**..
These are two label in one cell..

Answer (score 0):

For each of the label create the font and apply to the font property of that label.

```
+ (UIFont *)fontWithName:(NSString *)fontName size:(CGFloat)fontSize
```

Comment: But the size of label is fixed right?? I want to display same as in iPhone addres book.

Answer (score 0):

Make custom UITableViewCell.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        //Initialize String for Displaying
        //NSString *str = 

        UILabel *lbl;
        if ([cell.contentView.subviews count] == 0) {

            //Label alloc and init with frame
            //lbl = [[UILabel] alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];

            //Cofigure Label (text, font, etc.)
            lbl.text = str;
            //lbl.font = font;      

            //Add subview
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];

            //Release
            [lbl release];
        }
        else {
            lbl = [cell.contentView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];

            lbl.text = str; //Do only set variable value.
        }

        return cell;
    }
```