# Why my UITableView not smooth when scroll first time?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll, smoothing

My table view cell has four labels.
The table view is not smooth when scroll in first time. After all cells displayed one time, the scrolling is so smooth with no problem.
So I thought the problem is the speed of loading one cell in the first time.

I have reuse cell but the problem is not solved. Please help me! Thanks so much!

Here is my code:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ForumListTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSDictionary *cate = [_forums objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *forumsInCate = [cate objectForKey:@"forums"];
    NSDictionary *forumInfo = [forumsInCate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // title1
    UILabel *forumTitleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    forumTitleLabel.text = [forumInfo objectForKey:@"name"];

    // master
    UILabel *masterLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    NSString *master = [forumInfo objectForKey:@"moderators"];
    masterLabel.text = master;

    // title2
    UILabel  *threadTitleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    NSString *lastPostTitle;
    NSDictionary *lastPostInfo = [forumInfo objectForKey:@"lastpost"];
    lastPostTitle = [lastPostInfo objectForKey:@"subject"];
    threadTitleLabel.text = lastPostTitle;

    // author
    UILabel *authorLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
    authorLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@",
                        [forumInfo objectForKey:@"threads"],
                        [forumInfo objectForKey:@"posts"]
                        ];

    return cell;    
}
```

Comment: you dont seem to init/alloc your variables. dont think its related though. I would try on the simulator and device to see if this is reproducible.

Comment: I have inited all the vars in another function, so i think it may be  not the reason. I have tested it in simulator and it worked very well. It's very smooth in simulator, but not smooth in iPhone.

Comment: what iphone/OS is it slow on?

Comment: Are you sure that the identifier is set correctly in the .xib?

Comment: @TommyG iPhone4 with iOS 4.3.3

Comment: @blindJesse Yes, I have set the same identifier in xib.

Comment: See this link: [Fast Load Custom Cell][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952163/uitableviewcell-display-multiple-fonts/6952728#6952728

Comment: It seems a simple cell for it to be slow. If it takes time, is because it takes time to load the nib into memory. Does it have any UIImageView? Plus, I'd suggest you to have a look at the iOS 4 API UINib in order to only load the nib once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ForumListTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
```

**on .h**

```
NSArray *views;
```

**on .m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ForumListTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    //--- other object ----
    [views release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```