# How can I resize the size of the cell.textLabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I want to resize the default textLabel of a UITableViewCell because I display a image at the right of the rows. I Tryed with this code but it doesn't works, and I don't understand why.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
         //...
         cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 50);
         //...
    }
```

Comment: How do you display the image? Do you use a custom cell?

Comment: I Use the library HJCacheClasses and I create a HJManagedImageV object to put in the cells, but this object overlap the text of cell.textLabel. To avoid that, I want to resize the cell.textLabel frame, but doesn't work.

Comment: Geoffroy, check my answer and link. Customizing UIImageView is same with UILabel

Answer (score 3):

u should used custom label

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
{

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];

    UILabel *Lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75.0f, 4.5f, 360.0f, 20.0f)]; 
    [cell.contentView addSubview:Lbl];
    [Lbl release];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that is impossible.

Make custom cell.

```
UILabel myTextLabel;

//Set Frame and do something.

[cell.contentView addSubview:myTextLabel];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952163/uitableviewcell-display-multiple-fonts/6952728#6952728 this is my prev answer about custom cell. It would help you.

Answer (score 1):

textLabel is  readonly property so we can't set frame..

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) UILabel      *textLabel __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_3_0);   // default is nil.  label will be created if necessary.
@property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) UILabel      *detailTextLabel __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_3_0);   // default is nil.  label will be created if necessary (and the current style supports a detail label).
```

use custom cell ...

Answer (score 0):

You can not change a cell's textLabel's frame [**except**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824973/how-can-i-change-a-cells-textlabel-frame/4825245#4825245) or you go with custom cell and use UILabel, UIImageView as a subview of the cell.